# Apache Wicket error : Class does neither have a constructor with PageParameter nor a default constructor

Tags: java, forms, validation, wicket

My code

```
package com.remp.xyz;

import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Button;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.RequiredTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.validation.validator.EmailAddressValidator;
import org.apache.wicket.validation.validator.NumberValidator.RangeValidator;

public class FormValidation extends WebPage { 

    FormValidation(final PageParameters parameters) { 
        prepareComponent(); 
    }

    void prepareComponent() {
        FeedbackPanel feedBackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackMsg");

        Form<?> form = new Form<Object>("form");

        TextField<String> name = new RequiredTextField<String>("name", new Model<String>()); 
        TextField<Integer> age = new RequiredTextField<Integer>("age", new Model<Integer>()); 
        TextField<String> email = new RequiredTextField<String>("email", new Model<String>()); 
        TextField<String> zipcode = new RequiredTextField<String>("zipcode", new Model<String>()); 


        age.setType(Integer.class);
        age.add(RangeValidator.range(12, 60));
        email.add(EmailAddressValidator.getInstance());

        form.add(new Button("submit") { 

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                super.onSubmit();
            }
        });

    add(feedBackPanel);
    add(form);
    form.add(name);
    form.add(age);
    form.add(email);
    form.add(zipcode);

    }

}
```

I am getting below error :

```
Apache Wicket error : Class does neither have a constructor with PageParameter nor a default constructor
```

Is there something I am missing? obviously this class has a constructor so I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: What version of Wicket are you using?  You might be importing the wrong page parameters.  My code imports org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;

Comment: Improved question for better understanding

Comment: Constructor should be public but in your class you have used the default scope.

Comment: @AndreaDelBene give the best diagnose

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to steal Andrea Del Bene's points by giving his answer as proper answer this time:

> The constructor must have **public** visibility